# comm issues displaying desired results

Tags: comm

I learned here how to use comm to compare 2 already sorted (using sort) files and display lines/records present in either one of the files or in both of them.
Something is actually not really working as expected so I wanted to get some help.

Let's say I have a couple of sorted files that have about ~200k records each and some of those lines are common - appear in both files previously sorted. then execute this command:

```
comm -i -23 file1 file2 > test_01
```

very simple. the expectation being to have records/lines in test_01 that *only* show up in file1. but the output - test_01 - contains lines/records that are present in both files.

Both files contain just plain email addresses - one column each. and previously sorted, as mentioned above, with the sort utility. each file has different amounts of records. did confirm (using grep) that the test_01 output file contains records present in both file1 and file2.

based on the above process description is there something that i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I cannot find any man page that shows the `comm -i` option, What distro are you on? Also, `comm` is not a uniqueness test: if there are multiple occurrences in either file, any excess ones will be shown. Use `sort -u` to avoid this.

Comment: tried to format this message better to no avail:  COMM(1)                 FreeBSD General Commands Manual                COMM(1)\The following options are available:

     -1      Suppress printing of column 1, lines only in file1.

     -2      Suppress printing of column 2, lines only in file2.

     -3      Suppress printing of column 3, lines common to both.

     -i      Case insensitive comparison of lines.

Comment: same thing happens on osx. so the issue is related to the -i option. if i leave it out it seems to be working except have not tried to match case of the records in both files. i guess in order to be perfect the contents of each file have to be processed first to make sure the cases are only upper case or lower case for both

Answer (score 0):

Consider this illustration:

```
$ comm -23 L R > Z
$ head -n 9999 L R Z
==> L <==
Easy one
Easy one
Final Two

==> R <==
Easy one
Final Two

==> Z <==
Easy one
$
```

This lists column 1 containing "only" `Easy one`, although that text occurs in both files. One pair matches, the second is an excess line, only in file L. This is clear if all three columns are listed:

```
$ comm L R
        Easy one
Easy one
        Final Two
$
```

I cannot test the `-i` option on Linux, but there is no reason to suspect it does not work. However, `sort` does not have a `-i` option, so the inputs may be sorted by case and then compared without case.

I would suggest passing each file through `tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' | sort | uniq` before having `comm` check for differences.

It would be helpful if you showed a few lines of real data, and could isolate an example using only a few lines. It is possible that whitespace (space, tab, CR) is subtly affecting the results.

`awk` might be a better option. By using arrays, it can compare on unsorted data, equalise whitespace, ignore case, and still report the original line number and data .